# How can I manipulate a video stream in Java by treating it as a series of matrices or a data cube?

Tags: java, video, image-processing, video-processing

I am looking at Xuggler as a framework for decoding streaming video, but having troubles with two things:

1. Identifying a good Java library for matrix manipulation
2. Converting the video frames from Xuggler into matrices compatible with said library.

My Java is extremely rusty.  I've started by adapting some Xuggler tutorials to do the job.  Any recommendations for good Java Math libraries would be appreciated as well as approaches for converting BufferedImages to that library's image format.

Comment: I earned a tumbleweed badge.  Not sure if I should be proud of that.

Comment: I was looking for basically the same problem as what you described ... The lib you talk about seems pretty interesting. I'm gonna try some and bring feedbacks asap. Anyway, thanks for the lead !